# How to assign a value to specific locations of a matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix

I have matrix `int abc[2][2] = {x11,x12,x21,x22}` in I need to take user input on only x12 and x22 location and x11 and x21 are fixed value.

How to do that?

Comment: You are not being specific, and overthinking. Also, did you mean `int abc[2][2] = {{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}}`?

Comment: Indexes are **ZERO** based in C, your indexes for input are `abc[0][1]` and `abc[1][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

use as follows:

```
scanf("%d %d", &abc[0][1], &abc[1][1]);
```

a[0][1] --> 0th row first col i.e.x12

a[1][1] ---> first row first col i.e. x22

Note: can handler error of scanf as:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &abc[0][1], &abc[1][1]) != 2) {
  // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have a `2x2` array(`abc`). That means your array has `2` rows and`2` columns. It could be `nxm`. You can access or assign to an `nxm` array, using subscript notation, **remember array subscript start at `0` to `size - 1`.**

In your case to assign to location `n,m` `abc[n][m]` = `someInt`;

Reading and assigning to the location using scanf `scanf("%d %d", &abc[0][1], &abc[1][1])`. This correspond to what I think you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it's as simple your question suggest just use:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", abc[0] + 1, abc[1] + 1) != 2) {
  // error do something
}
```

Comment: Did I made a obvious error ? I'm a little tired so to tell me ;)

Comment: You didn't make an obvious error.  But by pointlessly using pointer arithmetic, you made all errors non-obvious.  Why not use `scanf("%d %d", &abc[0][1], &abc[1][1])`, which is obvious?

Comment: @SteveSummit I see. the reason is because I don't like it. Like I don't like do `&*a`. I don't like dereference for nothing. By the way, `&abc[0][1]` is pointer arithmetic. And for me, it's more obvious in my way, then your way. I think this coding style highlight the fact that `abc[i]` is a pointer and that how I code.